# IBM Domino - Denial of mail containing cert.id file

Tags: lotus-domino, email-attachments

I have attempted to send an organisational certifier as a mail attachment, and the Domino server denies it as an "attachment type policy violation".  There is nothing explicit in the server configuration that would explain this.  Other .id files are delivered without problem, and editing the name of the file so that "cert" does not appear as a substring in the file name does not help - the file is denied delivery even if the name entirely obscures its nature (e.g. "xx.id").  Only when I change the extension as well ("xx.yy") is it delivered successfully.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?  It looks as though there is a hard-coded policy against sending certifiers by mail, but is that really the case?

Answer (score 0):

The only place Domino could reject the mail is thru a router rule specified in the configuration document (Domino Directory -> Configuration Document -> Router/SMTP -> Restrictions and Controls -> Rules)

Other than that, there must be a Domino-external scanner which checks the file name or file content.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, that message isn't from Domino at all. When searching the Internet for "attachment type policy violation" (with the double quotes), I only find it in conjunction with Exchange 2010 servers. And your question of course.

Can you confirm that all mail servers in this case are Domino servers? Can you check the headers of the returned mail, in order to find out where the mail bounced? Can you check the log.nsf database of the Domino server, both under Mail Routing and Miscellaneous, to see if there's a message about the mail being rejected?

IMHO you should be barking up some Microsoft tree...